# How to export property values with django-import-export

Tags: python, django, django-import-export

My model:

```
class TreeNode(MPTTModel):
    ...
    @property
    def pay_progress(self):
        return "{}/{}".format(self.annuities.exclude(fact_date=None).aggregate(Sum('total'))['total__sum'] or 0,
                             self.annuities.aggregate(Sum('total'))['total__sum'])
```

Resources:

```
from import_export import resources
from models import TreeNode


class TreeNodeResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = TreeNode
```

View:

```
def export_treenode_csv(request):
    treenode_resource = TreeNodeResource()
    dataset = treenode_resource.export()
    response = HttpResponse(dataset.xls, content_type='application/vnd.ms-excel')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="TreeNode.xls"'

    return response
```

But this code exports only fields stored in database. How to add `pay_progress` property value to the exported report?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can take advantage of [dehydrate_<fieldname>](http://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started.html#advanced-data-manipulation) method:

```
class TreeNodeResource(resources.ModelResource):
    pay_progress = fields.Field()

    class Meta:
        model = TreeNode

    def dehydrate_pay_progress(self, node):
        return node.pay_progress
```

I find it a bit tedious; if someone has a better solution don't hesitate to posit it.

**Edit:**
you can use the named parameter `attribute` of a `Field` to get an object attribute/property without using *dehydrate()*:

```
class TreeNodeResource(resources.ModelResource):
    pay_progress = fields.Field(attribute='pay_progress')

    class Meta:
        model = TreeNode
```

It is also possible to [follow relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) using a double underscore.